# Right json format to parse date

Tags: codenameone

Each entity (`Serializable` & `PropertyBusinessObject`) in our app have a dateCreate and a dateUpdate field, which are of `Date` type.
So I've set two `Properties<Date, AbstractEntity>` and added them in the `PropertyIndex`.

To fill the entities, we use `getAsProperties` from the `RequestBuilder`, and every other property is correctly filled, but the two `Date` Properties have a `String` value which is the unparsed JSON value for this field.

Must the JSON have a particular format to be parsed as a Date ?

For now, I've put `dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS` as pattern for any `Date` on the server side, because it's the format outputed when I call `toJson` from the `PropertyIndex`, but it doesn't work.

EDIT : I've changed the format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` and figured the missing of quotes was because of the Map.toString I did to print values.
I've retrieved the Json with a `RequestBuilder.getAsString()` call and got this json:

```
{
    "dateCreate": "2018-10-02T22:00:00.000",
    "dateUpdate": null,
    "id": 209,
    "source": "Lorem ipsum",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum urna velit, pharetra id finibus eget, molestie id tortor.",
    "version": 1
}
```

The Json is well formed, but the entity's dateCreate is still an String and not a Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "unofficial" standard date format for JSON: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` which we implicitly use when parsing the JSON if the target value is a date. If you use this format to generate/parse the date on the server it should "just work".

Comment: Oh. I'm stupid, I have not seen that I inverted the date... Thanks !

Comment: But after a try, still a string. I found that in the JSON from my server, the values are not double quoted, maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: They should be quoted

Comment: I'll try to change that tomorrow

Comment: I've edited the question, the Json is well formed, but the Date property still contains a String and not a Date

Comment: When creating the property date instance did you pass in Date.class as the type? Notice that the generic type isn't enough because the compiler erases the generics.

Comment: I didn't, I just have tried with the Date.class in the property constructor and now it's working ! Thanks ! I didn't know the class was mandatory.

Comment: It's needed when you are relying on type information as you are in this case.